# Laravel link_to_route function

Tags: php, laravel

I have this bit of code:

```
<li> {!! link_to_route('get_register', 'Register' ) !!} </li>
```

As you can see i used the link_to_route function. I defined this Route in this bit of code:

```
Route::group (['prefix' => 'auth'], function() {

Route::get('register',[
'as' => 'get_register',
'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@get_register'
    ]);

Route::post('register',[
'as' => 'post_register',
'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@post_register'
    ]);


});
```

Now when i go to my page in the browser i get the following error:

http://prntscr.com/cniild

Anything that could help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

-Kevin

Comment: Which version of the framework laravel?
In 5 laravel no link_to_route().

Comment: Im using laravel 5 @IlyaYaremchuk

Comment: then so: <a href="{!! route('get_register') !!}">register</a>

Comment: Thanks @IlyaYaremchuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link_to_route` was part of the Laravel HTML library which was removed in Laravel 5. It is now maintained by [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html), so you will need to install their package to use that function. Camilo's solution is the standard way to link to named routes now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a

```
<a href="{{ route('get_register') }}">Register</a>
```

I hope this help

Comment: Thanks it helped :)